# WPF Strange problem with dynamically binding items to a new ListBox

Tags: wpf

here's the code. All it does is, it creates a new ListBox control inside a StackPanel and adds to it a new Item. The problem is described at the bottom of the page.

**MyWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="itemsTemplate">
        <Border Width="200" Height="50" >
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Title}" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=DataItems}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemsTemplate}">
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

**MyWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    private ObservableCollection<MyDataItem> dataItems;

    public ObservableCollection<MyDataItem> DataItems
    {
        get { return dataItems; }
    }

    public Window1()
    {
        dataItems = new ObservableCollection<MyDataItem>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

**MyDataItem.cs**

```
public class MyDataItem : DependencyObject
{
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), 
                                    typeof(MyDataItem), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

    public MyDataItem(string title)
    {
        Title = title;
    }
}
```

**Add a new Listbox with item**

```
    void addNewItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyDataItem item = new MyDataItem("12");
        dataItems.Add(item);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

after that action, I see that new ListBox control, but all its item's characters are treated as a separate items as You can see @ the picture. Why ?

[image: the result]

> **`[ EDIT ]`**

solved, I had to change from string to List everywhere in that class:

```
public class MyDataItem : DependencyObject
{
    public List<string> Title
    {
        get
        {
            return (List<string>)GetValue(TitleProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), 
                                    typeof(MyDataItem), 
                                    new UIPropertyMetadata(new List<string>()));

    public MyDataItem(List<string> title)
    {
        Title = title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are giving data source as string.. it is converting that string to collection (character array) since itemssource property will always be collection..

if you still want to create a list box in data template with single item (in you case it is Title).. then try this..

Change you title property to List and while creating your title create a list which contains one string . so item source will be list and since itemssource contains one string it will create only one item.

Comment: hmm as I remembered (right now I don't have access to the code) when I've changed the Title  property from string to List<string> that code generates an exception about the wrong type

Comment: well you have to change the peoperty type in many places like... while creating property and creating dependency property

Comment: I've done it already, in the MyDataItem.cs I've replaced all 'string' => 'List<string>'

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, because you declared to instantiate a listbox for each item. Since an item is exposing a string (thus an array of characters), the listbox shows correctly one char for every row.

Why do you insert an ItemsControl (the listbox) inside another ItemsControl?

Cheers

Comment: I know, all I wanna do is to add a new ListBox with an item inside it. It works fine, but the problem is as you describe it in your 2nd sentence.